# android picasso invalidate not working

Tags: android, caching, picasso

```
if(isConnected()) { // if device online
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() { }
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(context).invalidate(url);
                }
            });
} else { // if device offline
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) // force load cached image
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Earlier I had an image on my server. I fetched that image using picasso and it was cached.

Now I deleted that image, so I want to invalidate that image in picasso cache. Now on refreshing the imageview when device is online, the imageview was blank and onError was executed, as per expected.

BUT,

Now when the device is offline, the else part is executed and since I've given networkpolicy.offline, picasso will be forced to show cached image, which should not exist since I had invalidated it before. Still it shows the image from the cache. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this to invalidate your image path:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).invalidate(ImagePath + ".jpg");
```

and to load your image use:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(ImagePath+".jpg").networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).error(R.drawable.ic_new).into(Imageview);
```

Comment: They key here is that invalidate() only clears from the meemory cache NOT the networking chache

Comment: then how to clear both the memory and network  cache

Comment: For picasso version 2.5.2 I used .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)